# How would my collapsible sword blade work?

Tags: science-fiction, weapons, swords

The collapsible sword in question would be:

- 3 feet / 90 cm long total length of handle + blade.  The blade would be 2 feet / 60 cm long, and the handle would be 1 foot / 30 cm long. (Handle could be a couple inches longer, or blade a couple inches shorter if necessary)
- The blade would expand out of the handle with the push of a switch or latch located on the handle.
- The blade must be prevented from collapsing back on itself for thrusts.
- The blade would be made of a hard/strong material such as a metal, polymer, etc. that could keep a sharp/durable edge.
- The blade should be strong enough to block other weapons such as swords (at least like a saber or other short sword) without breaking.
- Single-edged.  (Likely similar to a short samurai sword).
- The mechanism couldn’t be a telescoping system.

Some potential mechanisms:

- Multiple separate metal pieces that latch/hinge together?
- Powerful electromagnetic field holds pieces together?
- Nano particles?
- Shape memory alloy?

I’m open to other creative ideas that would achieve the same result as well.

The sword should use scientifically achievable technology, no magic is involved.

Comment: What you describe presumes that a modern sword has unnecessary material that could be removed so that the sword could fit into the handle. I assure you that this is not the case.

Comment: Also, remember that [tag:science-based] and [tag:science-fiction] are mutually exclusive. You're allowed to use only one.

Comment: @JBH - the duplicate question is completely different. The stresses and forces on a sword blade are substantially different to those faced by a Rifle barrel. I do not consider these to be remotely similar.

Comment: A lot depends on what kind of sword we're talking about (single edge/double edge, broad blade/slender blade) and what kinds of swords it needs to block. Also what kind of durability are we looking at, as even "normal" swords can bend, chip or break under regular use.

Comment: @JBH, I removed one of those tags.  And I concur with TheDemonLord, the “duplicate” question is entirely different and useless for what I’m asking about.

Comment: maybe you could get one of those magic flexible swords from Highlander series :-)

Comment: This question should be reopened, because the “duplicate” answer is nothing like my question, and is useless to me.

Comment: @TheDemonLord No, they're not particularly different. Both are constructions suffering forces both perpendicular and parallel. Both introduce weaknesses that compromise the fundamental purpose of the object. And they're so much alike that the one answer that slipped in before I VTC'd (and before the OP made edits to circumvent the issue) introduced the same alteration: telescoping. I've no objection to the community overriding my VTC, but you and the OP are both quite wrong. Indeed, without telescoping, the blade will never be strong enough. Unless a switchblade is all we're talking about.

Comment: @JBH  THEY ARE PARTICULARLY DIFFERENT, because I already said that a telescoping system wouldn’t fit within my metrics.  A telescoping mechanism is the ASSUMED mechanism of the other question.  In the other question, the OP REQUESTED a telescoping mechanism, where in my question, I said that a telescoping mechanism WOULDN’T WORK (well I notice I originally said “wouldn’t likely work, so I just edited it to make it clearer) for my situation!  They are entirely different, and the answers in the other question are completely useless and irrelevant to my situation and my question.

Comment: @JBH They are completely different. What makes a Telescoping mechanism for a sword useless is not the same reasons why telescoping barrels aren't used. Case in point - you can mount a Suppressor on the end of a Firearm quite easily - the Firearm isn't going to have a catastrophic failure when used as intended. Add an extension onto a sword, take a single swing and watch the blade deform and or shatter. I'm fine with closing as a bad question - but as a Duplicate? This is not even remotely the same.

Comment: @TheDemonLord Um... a suppressor is not an extension of the barrel and not an example of a "telescoping barrel." An actual telescoping barrel is good for nothing but shotguns - and bad ones at that (see "blunderbuss"). The only way to make a collapsible blade that isn't just a folding or hidden blade (switchblade) is a telescoping blade - and thus any solution that works for the gun, works for the blade. If 2+2 = 4 = 1+3 then 2+2 = 1+3. Duplicate question.

Comment: @KalMadda You didn't add the "no telescoping solutions" condition until ***after*** I closed your question. See revision #4 of your own question, which came after my closure.

Comment: @JBH I’m pretty sure I said in a comment that the telescoping solution wouldn’t be a good solution in a comment before you closed it.  In that same comment, I specifically asked about a solution that would use several solid blade pieces with some form of lock or hinge mechanism.  Even if we assumed a telescoping system would work well, a telescoping barrel is very different from a telescoping sword blade.

Comment: @JBH  “…and thus any solution that works for the gun, works for the blade. If 2+2 = 4 = 1+3 then 2+2 = 1+3. Duplicate”.   Except that’s not the way it works!  Even if a telescoping blade worked, which I already concluded it wouldn’t work well, any solution for a TUBE-shaped barrel will not just automatically work for a WEDGE-shaped blade that has to have a sharp edge!

Comment: @KalMadda I'm sorry, Kal, but that's simply not true. The prism vs. cylindrical argument simply isn't enough to rationalize a significant difference. Even the issue of forces isn't enough. Your collapsible blade, barring any kind of magic (including Clarkean) has only three options: solid-blade-hidden-in-handle (switchblade), articulated/hinged-blade, and telescoping-blade. A switchblade-style sword really is impractical. I happen to own one (a butterfly). An articulated blade will never be strong enough. A telescoping blade can be strong enough - but that brings us back to the duplication.

Comment: @JBH  Think whatever you want, that doesn’t make it true.  I’m just glad my question was reopened so that maybe I can get some answers that are actually relevant to my situation and needs.

Comment: BTW Kal, Please note that *nothing you say in a comment means beans.* Until you [edit] your post to include it, it's just noise. No one is obligated to read comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soft frame challenge - Cyberpunk street ninjas are not materials science Ph.Ds and they don't care how their hardware works on a molecular level.

Imagine how ridiculous it would be to describe a real technology down to the materials science that makes it work the way it does.

> The ninja drew his sword. Iron lattices have a conduction band in
> which it doesn't take a lot of energy to move electrons around. Thus,
> because reflectivity is coupled to conductivity by the Hagens-Ruben
> equation, it gleamed wickedly in the moonlight as the ninja stalked
> silently towards his victim...

Your fictional sword *just works*. The fictional materials science that makes it work is irrelevant except that, once you've invented a fictional fact, you're stuck with it. You can just say:

> With a flick of his wrist, the ninja unfolded his collapsible sword. A
> coded pulse of electricity locked its superalloy segments together
> into a single deadly blade, and he stalked silently towards his
> victim.

Bam, you're done. The only further thought you need to give to it is that you're now working in a setting in which coded pulses of electricity [or some other science thing of your choice] can cause superalloy segments to lock together (because of materials science that your characters don't care about).

In the long run, the knock-on consequences of what kind of fictional materials science allows for collapsible ninja swords may even be be why you have a collapsible ninja sword in your story in the first place, since it's a convenient way to introduce that fact about the way the rules are slightly different in your setting.

Comment: @g s  Thank you for the answer.  You actually provided a plausible explanation in your answer with coded pulses of electricity locking together superalloy segments.  This was the kind of thing I was hoping for, I don’t have to describe all of the workings in super-fine detail or anything, but I was hoping for answers like yours that would provide a plausible way for the blade to be formed that could theoretically work.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but it won't.

With a handle that is 1 foot long, 2-feet long blade means, unfortunately, that you need a telescopic blade. Without [handwavium](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/handwavium), it will be structurally too weak for any proper use because at least half of the length of the blade has to be hollow. It cannot be strong enough to block other weapons without breaking.

Comment: But couldn’t the blade potentially be stored in smaller solid sections that could hinge or lock somehow together?

Comment: You are right, that is an option, too. However, a hinge in the middle of the blade is problematic as well exactly for the same reason: *anything* that can move compromises structural integrity.

Comment: But is there a hinge/locking mechanism combo that would be durable enough for parrying/blocking other weapons?  I’m sure it wouldn’t necessarily be as strong as a solid blade could potentially be, but could it be strong enough?

Comment: @KalMadda I think you underestimate how much force a sword swing has. Peak impact can be as high as 27KN - a Hinge or Lock that is sufficiently sturdy to take that kind of impact force is going to be big and bulky - ruining the other attributes of the sword.

Comment: The problem with moving parts is that all stress from impacts concentrates on very small part of the blade, and the moving parts also introduce discontinuities that make it even worse. If the blade is a more or less homogeneous piece of metal, the stress is distributed evenly, and thus the blade can withstand much more. An extreme example is glass that is scratched: heating up and cooling the glass down repeatedly makes the glass break where the scratch is, and the scratch does not even need to be deep. Slight discontinuity together with stress is all it takes to break it.

Comment: Also, if we're talking about metals, hardness (the ability to maintain an edge) and toughness (the ability to absorb impacts without breaking) are usually in a balance, if you increase one, the other decreases. Furthermore, while metals can have good elasticity (i.e. they return to their original shape after deformation), blocking an attack (rather than deflecting) can put forces into it where it will deform plastically. That's not a problem for normal swords but very much is if you have to somehow pack it back into the space it came from. So I'd restrict collapsible blades to thrusting.